# can not do sorting for using startScroll method with spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

im using spring-data-elasticsearch for developing api with es as backend. and im using `startScroll(long scrollTimeInMillis, SearchQuery searchQuery, Class<T> clazz)` method for getting results from elasticsearch. but sort is not working.

i set sorting in the searchQuery as follows.

```
NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withIndices(<indices>).withTypes(<types>).withSort(<sort>)
```

and in  i added the following for `<sort>`

```
new FieldSortBuilder("created_at").unmappedType("date").order(SortOrder.valueOf("ASC"))
```

i also tried putting sort in pageable like below.

```
NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withIndices(<indices>).withTypes(<types>).withPageable(<pageable>)
```

and in  i added the following for `<pageable>`

```
Sort sortRequest = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.valueOf('ASC'), "created_at")
PageRequest.of(<pageNumber>, <pageSize>, sortRequest)
```

both isn't working.
and i start to think maybe scroll does not support sorting.

expected is for the result to show in order of created_at ASC.
but now its just randomly retrieved.

Comment: can you provide a minimal runnable example with the necessary classes and some test data to reproduce this? Also it would be necessary to know which versions of ES, Spring and spring-data-elasticsearch you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem using 3.2, and I notice that 4.0 has resolved it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).